# python os.path.realpath not working properly

Tags: python, path, chdir, realpath

I have following code:

```
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/../test")
path.append(os.getcwd())
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

Which should add `/../test` to python path, and it does so, and it all runs smoothly afterwards on eclipse using PyDev.

But when I lunch same app from console second os.chdir does something wrong, actually the wrong thing is in `os.path.realpath(__file__)` cus it returns `../test/myFile.py` in stead of `../originalFolder/myFile.py`. Of course I can fix this by using fixed `os.chdir("../originalFolder")` but that seems a bit wrong to me, but this works on both, eclipse and console.

P.S. I'm using `os.getcwd()` actually because I want to make sure there isn't such folder already added, otherwise I wouldn't have to switch dir's at all

So is there anything wrong with my approach or I have messed something up? or what? :)

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look what is value of `__file__`. It doesn't contain absolute path to your script, it's a value from command line, so it may be something like "./myFile.py" or "myFile.py". Also, realpath() doesn't make path absolute, so realpath("myFile.py") called in different directory will still return "myFile.py".

I think you should do ssomething like this:

```
import os.path

script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
target_dir = os.path.join(script_dir, '..', 'test')
print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir(target_dir)
print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir(script_dir)
print(os.getcwd())
```

On my computer (Windows) I have result like that:

```
e:\parser>c:\Python27\python.exe .\rp.py
e:\parser
e:\test
e:\parser

e:\parser>c:\Python27\python.exe ..\parser\rp.py
e:\parser
e:\test
e:\parser
```

**Note:** If you care for compatibility (you don't like strange path errors) you should use **os.path.join()** whenever you combine paths.

**Note:** I know my solution is dead simple (remember absolute path), but sometimes simplest solutions are best.

Comment: `realpath()` makes path absolute

Comment: [Here](http://helpful.knobs-dials.com/index.php/Python_usage_notes/Filesystem_stuff)'s a good summary of which command does what.

Comment: Although this is not the most popular question on this topi, this answer is the most correct one. Thank you !