# How to get absolute path on linux when running from another location

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I want to run a crontab which will run my file every hour at 0 minutes. I have the (sudo) crontab set up with a single command as follows:

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /usr/folder/test.py
```

The crontab is running and as far as I can tell is correct, but my python file is not returning the absolute path when the file is run from another location.

What I need is a way to guarantee the absolute path of this text file when it is accessed from the root so that my crontab can run the file.

I've tried using both `Path(filename).resolve()`, and `os.path.abspath(filename)` but neither of them work.

```py
import os
print(os.path.abspath("checklist.txt"))
```

```sh
python3 usr/folder/test.py
```

When I run the file "test.py" while within the folder, I get the expected output

> python3 test.py
>
> /usr/folder/checklist.txt

however when I run the same file from the root and access it via a path I get a different result, making using crontab impossible in this context

> python3 usr/folder/test.py
>
> /checklist.txt

Comment: [What is the 'working directory' when cron executes a job?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38951), [How to get full path of current file's directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3430372/608639), [Why would one use both, os.path.abspath and os.path.realpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37863476/608639), [python os.path.realpath not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9887259/608639), etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `checklist.txt` is in the same folder as your `test.py` script, then you can use the `__file__` variable to get the right path. For example

```py
# The directory that 'test.py' is stored
directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
# The path to the 'checklist.txt'
checklist_path = os.path.join(directory, 'checklist.txt')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Been pulling my hair out over this for hours.

Answer (score 2):

**__file__ attribute**

```
import os
filename = 'checklist.txt'
abs_path_to_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), filename)
```

---

**sys module**

```
import os, sys
filename = 'checklist.txt'
abs_path_to_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), filename)
```